# detect if string contains unclosed html tags [php]

Tags: php, html, tags

I was wondering if there is a possiblity to detect if string contains unclosed tags and if so strip that tag away or close him. So for instance I have:

`<p>lorem ipsum dolor..</p> some other text <em> em tag unclosed`

As you can see there is unclosed tag and will cause an issue for the browser if we render that as HTML. So I would like to close that tag or just strip him if is unclosed (stripping is actually easy, what is hard to do is detection).

Is that possible in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

You could utilise [DOMDocument](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) for that

```
$doc = new \DomDocument();
$stringToTest = \mb_convert_encoding($stringToTest, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8');
$doc->loadHTML($stringToTest, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

For your example that produces

```
<p>lorem ipsum dolor..<p> some other text <em> em tag unclosed</em></p></p>
```

Note: First of all it would be better to just not generate broken HTML at all. And as a backup you should leave it up to the browser fixing it (since browsers are very very good in that).

Comment: Is it possible to keep special characters like bullet etc? Tried with v.1 and UTF-8 but still does not work. It gives me some weird characters.

Comment: That is where the fun part starts - encodings :) As I said above: Avoid generating broken HTML. If you don't generate it: Let the browsers fix it as they do it since decades for us and thus are very good in that. Added `mb_convert_encoding` to the answer.